# Jupyter notebook failed to load DLL

Tags: jupyter-notebook

When i am starting jupyter notebook from cmd prompt i get following error

```
C:\Users\Ganesh>jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 46, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 27, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I had set following paths in system variable

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3Scripts\jupyter
```

Did i missed any path to add in system variables
(OS version Windows 10)

Answer (score 9):

Try to add the following directories to your env path as well:
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\usr\bin
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin

Answer (score 4):

First enter
`activate base`

then enter 
`jupyter notebook`

This works for me

Answer (score 3):

I might be late but in cmd type: `conda run jupyter notebook`

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when creating a new environment with the latest anaconda package (at the time of my answer at least). The folder zmq in the base environment ([1] .../Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/zmq) was correct, it was actually the folder zmq in the new environment ([2] {python_env_dir}/{env}/.../site-packages/zmq) that was corrupted.

Solution: I deleted the folder [2], and I copied the folder [1] in the previous place of the folder [2]. And this issue was solved for me.

Comment: Could you explain what you meant by "replaced"?

Comment: Sorry, yes, it was not clear at all, I will edit my answer

Comment: This is exactly what solved it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

yes, what @mountrix said was the case also when the error happened to me. this one fixes it in the most simple way (answer from Alex W): https://stackoverflow.com/a/54225033/12107973

Answer (score -1):

Enter activate base to activate environment
and then  jupyter notebook to start the server.
It will work.