# Import error while trying to run jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, dllimport

An import error occurs when trying to run `jupyter` notebook

I'm trying to run `jupyter` notebook using `anaconda` (`git bash` platform), and as I type in `jupyter` notebook, an import error occurs every time. I tried to lauch it inside an environment, but the same error occured.

```
$ jupyter notebook
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in
 <module>
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 47, in <module>
from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
from zmq import backend
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
reraise(*exc_info)
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
_ns = select_backend(first)
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 27, in select_backend
mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from . import (constants, error, message, context,
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

***EDITED***
After reinstalling pyzmq (and I tried reinstalling conda too), the following error occurs:

```
$ jupyter notebook
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):    File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py",
>   line 10, in  
>        import sqlite3
>
> File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\sqlite3__init__.py", line 23, in
>   
>        from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
>
> File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in
>
> ```
> from _sqlite3 import *
> ```
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6,
>   in
>
> ```
> from notebook.notebookapp import main
> ```
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py",
>   line 86, in
>
> ```
> from .services.sessions.sessionmanager import SessionManager
> ```
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py",
>   line 13, in
>
> ```
> from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
> ```
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'

Comment: That's python unable to `import sqlite3`. Can you do that in an interactive interpreter?

Answer (score 13):

I found a [similar issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3435) open on GitHub for zmq. The recommendation by GitHub user [harsh23tyagi](https://github.com/harsh23tyagi) that seems to work for most is to run the following:

```
pip uninstall pyzmq
pip install pyzmq
```

Comment: Thanks, it partially solved my problem, I've edited my question with the now error...

Comment: @BenedekDér Try running `pip install pysqlite2` to see if it resolves that error

Comment: This resolves an issue which appears in various different forms, related to zmq, pywin32, Pycharm and Anaconda (64-bit). In my case, when I was starting Jupyter from the Anaconda `base` environment everything worked normally. With other environments I would get an error, even if `jupyter notebook` was invoked from Anaconda Prompt, independent of Pycharm. Setting up a clean environment only, didn't help. What did help was setting up a clean environment and then running the uninstall/install of pyzmq *with pip*, from the terminal, within the activated environment.

Answer (score 3):

Working with conda env, `jupyter notebook` worked in (base) env but gave the .libzmq error in (my_env).
To be able to run notebooks from my_env, this worked for me :

- `pip uninstall pyzmq`
- `pip install pyzmq==20` (no version for pyzmq didn't fix the issue for me)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that updating pyzmq to the latest version fixes this problem for me.

```
conda install pyzmq=22
```

Answer (score 0):

- Open Anaconda Navigator
- Go to Jupyter Notebook Setting (icon on the right hand side corner)
- And select install specific version After installation select new installation and open it. It will work !!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a change in module structure with jupyter notebook version 7. Downgrading the notebook version to 6.5 worked for me.
Maybe this can work
pip3 install notebook==6.5.5

Comment: At the time the OP was posted, this didn't involve Jupyter Notebook 7+ as it didn't exist. Additionally, the original post was directed at using the Aanconda distribution and you should hesitate to ever advise using `pip` to install anything where there is Anaconda/conda recipe. The choice was made to use Anaconda/conda as the primary package manager and that should always be the primary way to adjust the environment(s).