# I am trying to run Hydrogen for atom on Windows 10. When I try to run code, it displays long error message

Tags: python, hydrogen

I am trying to run code via Hydrogen in Atom, but when I try to, all I get is this error:

```
traceback (most recent call last): 
file "c:\users\maxsc_000\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main "main", mod_spec) 
file "c:\users\maxsc_000\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals) 
file "c:\users\maxsc_000\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in from ipykernel import kernelapp as app file "c:\users\maxsc_000\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel__init__.py", line 2, in from .connect import 
file "c:\users\maxsc_000\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 18, in import jupyter_client 
file "c:\users\maxsc_000\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client__init__.py", line 4, in from .connect import 
file "c:\users\maxsc_000\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 24, in import zmq 
file "c:\users\maxsc_000\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq__init__.py", line 47, in from zmq import backend 
file "c:\users\maxsc_000\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend__init__.py", line 40, in reraise(*exc_info) 
file "c:\users\maxsc_000\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise raise value 
file "c:\users\maxsc_000\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend__init__.py", line 27, in _ns = select_backend(first) 
file "c:\users\maxsc_000\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend mod = import(name, fromlist=public_api) 
file "c:\users\maxsc_000\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython__init__.py", line 6, in from . import (constants, error, message, context, 
importerror: dll load failed: das angegebene modul wurde nicht gefunden.
```

Does anyone know why this error occurs?

Comment: Could you share the code with us?

Comment: It does not matter which code I am trying to run, whatever code I decide to run produces exactly this error.

Comment: Which version of python are you running?

Comment: First, it says that my kernel, Python, is updated, and immediately the before mentioned error occurs

Comment: I am using python 3.7.4

Comment: Per [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/nteract/hydrogen/issues/1550#issuecomment-479158935) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54225033/7867968), I think you just need to re-install `zmq`

Comment: Re-installing zmq actually solved my problem. Thas was very quick! Thank you, everybody!

Answer (score 0):

This is a well known problem in Atom mentioned [here](https://github.com/nteract/hydrogen/issues/1550), [here](https://github.com/nteract/hydrogen/issues/1405), and [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10422#issuecomment-448185070)

There are two possible solutions I could find. Namely:

"Atom recommends starting from terminal. This will make it simple to understand which environment you are launching atom in and which project/directory you want atom to open. Plus, it is much more stylish .

In your terminal of choice (e.g. powershell, cmd.exe, bash for windows, anaconda prompt):

`> cd .\my\project\folder`

`> atom .`

`So if you want to change env, you just activate my-env and start atom again with atom .`"

and:

"I solved it by installing python 3.6 instead of 3.7."

and:

"We do not support using our software outside of proper activation (anaconda prompt, navigator, manually running the activation scripts).

To run the activation scripts:

> cmd.exe: \Scripts\activate.bat
>   MSYS2 (or Git for Windows):
>
> source /Scripts/activate

MSYS2 is better supported than Git for Windows but likely either will work fine." - mingwandroid

and **if you are using miniconda**:

"You have to add THREE miniconda related paths to PATH env-variable

> C:\tools\miniconda3
>
> C:\tools\miniconda3\Scripts
>
> C:\tools\miniconda3\Library\bin"

basically you need to make sure you've yet up conda properly, using a virtual env, starting atom in console and preferably using the conda prompt.

This is my second post on SO so I hope I helped and have a nice day!