# Jupyter notebook does not launch (ImportError: DLL load failed while importing)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Recently my jupyter notebook stopped launching. When I try the command `jupyter notebook` from anaconda prompt but it gives error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Dell\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
> from notebook.notebookapp import main
> File "C:\Users\Dell\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 51, in 
> from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
> File "C:\Users\Dell\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq_*init*_.py", line 50, in 
> from zmq import backend
> File "C:\Users\Dell\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend_*init*_.py", line 40, in 
> reraise(*exc_info)
> File "C:\Users\Dell\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
> raise value
> File "C:\Users\Dell\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend_*init*_.py", line 27, in 
> *ns = select_backend(first)
>
> File "C:\Users\Dell\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
> mod = **import**(name, fromlist=public_api)
>
> File "C:\Users\Dell\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython_*init**.py", line 6, in 
> from . import (constants, error, message, context,
> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing error: The specified module could not be found.

I even tried reinstalling anaconda and upgraded to python 3.8.3 on windows 10 but still get the same error. When I tried to check jupyter notebook's version it said that ipykernel and some other things were not installed. `jupyter --version` gives me this:

> jupyter core     : 4.6.3
> jupyter-notebook : 6.1.1
> qtconsole        : 4.7.6
> ipython          : 7.18.1
> ipykernel        : not installed
> jupyter client   : not installed
> jupyter lab      : not installed
> nbconvert        : 5.6.1

But installing ipykernel with `conda install ipykernel` says

> All requested packages already installed.

I also tried `ipython kernel install --name <env_name> --user` but this gives another dll error.

Reading some other problems in stackoverflow I went and checked my enviroment variables.

[image: System Variables]

[image: User Variables]

Is there a problem with this environment variable. Please help.

Screenshot of the anaconda prompt with error.
[image: Screenshot of the anaconda prompt]

**Edit:** The anaconda navigator does not launch either. `anaconda-navigator` on the anaconda prompt gives another error:
[image: Anaconda navigator error]

I also tried:

```
conda install qt --force
conda install pyqt --force
```

But that did'nt help. Does previously installed anaconda cause such error?

Comment: Please attach screenshot of your error in anaconda prompt maybe your directory is not right

Comment: @MuhammadRizwanMunawar I added the screenshot of anaconda prompt. It was working fine untill i tried to install openCV. Not so sure if that caused the error but i just tried pip installing it.

Comment: Please try without opencv...

Comment: If OpenCV Cause error so install opencv with command pip install opencv-python

Comment: Also please try to add C:\user\Dell\Anaconda in Your envirnoment variable i think that error

Comment: @MuhammadRizwanMunawar I've already removed opencv and python 3.7 and installed python 3.8 and new version of anaconda. adding the anaconda3 path to the environment variable didnot work either.

Comment: Please unistall anaconda and then try to download from link [https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda2-5.3.0-Windows-x86_64.exe] and install it

Comment: New Version of anaconda and jupyter sometimes give error

Comment: @MuhammadRizwanMunawar thanks a lot for your time but the link you provided says 404 error. I'm still waiting for your update on the answer below to be accepted. I recently noticed that the anaconda navigator does not launch either i'll update my question with the error i get there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import error while trying to run jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54224969/import-error-while-trying-to-run-jupyter-notebook)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found what I did wrong (silly me). **Microsoft visual C++ 2015-2019** was somehow removed when I tried to install openCV manually. Didn't think that such an install would make such big impact, have to keep that in mind now but installing the latest solved all the problems.

P.S.: This solution might not work for someone else with similar problem. But its worth taking a note.

Comment: Thank you every one who cared to come with a solution for their time. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

Just for other people having similar issue.

In my case, when I run `jupyter notebook` on command line, I got the same error as @Anav Katwal . However if I run `jupyter notebook` on **Anaconda Prompt**, then the error is gone.

If you truly want to execute `jupyter notebook` on cmd, then you could add the following paths to your system environment variable:

- `C:\Users\USERNAME\anaconda3\Library\bin`
- `C:\Users\USERNAME\anaconda3\Scripts`
- `C:\Users\USERNAME\anaconda3\condabin`

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was reinstalling one of the modules jupyter calls and reinstalling the newer version manually, via another SO answer:

```
pip uninstall pyzmq 
pip install pyzmq==20
```

[Import error while trying to run jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54224969/import-error-while-trying-to-run-jupyter-notebook/54225033#54225033)

Answer (score 0):

step 1 : close anaconda and vscode

step 2 : open command prompt (cmd) and uninstall jupyter lab

```
pip uninstall jupyterlab
```

step 3: now open jupyter lab type

```
jupyter-lab
```

Now open vs code jupyter notebook start working

Answer (score -1):

Use this code, instead of conda

```
pip install jupyter
```

Comment: Tried uninstalling and reinstalling with pip. It did'nt help

Comment: @AnavKatwal I Updated his answer once it accepted then it will be shown to you, try to follow that one in order to run jupyter. Thanks