# I installed python 3.9.1 but can not open jupyter notebook or jupyterlab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I just install and even reinstalled but when I try to open  jupuyterlab or p notebook it gives following error

```
 File "c:\users\v\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\v\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\v\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.EXE\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\users\v\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 49, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "c:\users\v\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    _load_libzmq()
  File "c:\users\v\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 28, in _load_libzmq
    from . import libzmq
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing libzmq: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: 1. Which commands do you use to install the packages? 2. Try to uninstall and reinstall zmq, as the error mentioned. 3. If nothing works you can still try to downgrade to Python 3.8 or 3.7, you might need to do that in the future anyway (some popular packages still doesn't support 3.9)

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63979186/jupyter-notebook-does-not-launch-importerror-dll-load-failed-while-importing

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was able to resolve it by uninstalling pyzmq and reinstalling it with an older version

```
pip uninstall pyzmq

pip install pyzmq==20.0.0
```