# Can not open Jupyter Notebook. getting error " DLL load failed while importing libzmq: The specified module could not be found."

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am new to Python. I have installed Python 3.9 and Jupyter notebook without Anaconda. When I try to open it in CMD I am getting the error i have copied below.

I tried:

```
pip uninstall zmq
pip install zmq
```

but it did not help.

```
C:\Users\Lana>jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\lana\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\lana\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Lana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.EXE\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\users\lana\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 49, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "c:\users\lana\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    _load_libzmq()
  File "c:\users\lana\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 28, in _load_libzmq
    from . import libzmq
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing libzmq: The specified module could not be found.
```

and here is the set up

```
 C:\Users\Lana>jupyter --version
jupyter core     : 4.7.0
jupyter-notebook : 6.1.6
qtconsole        : 5.0.1
ipython          : 7.19.0
ipykernel        : not installed
jupyter client   : not installed
jupyter lab      : not installed
nbconvert        : not installed
ipywidgets       : not installed
nbformat         : 5.0.8
traitlets        : 5.0.5
```

Comment: Did you follow some guide for the installation?

Comment: There is no guide You just download it from the website. I saw someone else had the same issue and posted here yesterday. It is the newest version of Python 3.9.1 and i am thinking there is a bug....I have downloaded 3.8 version and did not have the same issue. I was able to install Jupiter without any errors.

Comment: I don't suggest diving into this kind of bug, just info: when dealing with Python on Windows, https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ is a place where one can get complete, compiled "wheel" files which sometimes helps with DLL-issues.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the exact same problem. But in this case, I installed Anaconda (along with just python): this caused conflict between the python versions (3.8.5 and 3.8.6). I was then able to resolve the issue by uninstalling and reinstalling the pyzmq with the older version (it's a different version by default):

```
pip uninstall pyzmq

pip install pyzmq==20.0.0
```

I got this answer from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65574748/i-installed-python-3-9-1-but-can-not-open-jupyter-notebook-or-jupyterlab).